# Wamp PHP wont load

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

i don't know what i did wrong here.

My wamp has green status, PHP is running fine but it wont open up my project.

Ps: Its working fine on my other computer.

[Wamp Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXJAH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per screen-shot attached, 
Your project base path is

> c:\wanp64\www\phpJoaozinhoEgay

`header.php` file located on this location try to inlcude file `head.php` located on

> C:\xampp\htdocs\phpJoaozinhoEgay

Might be in your project configuration you need to change the project base path from `C:\xampp\htdocs\phpJoaozinhoEgay` to `c:\wanp64\www\phpJoaozinhoEgay`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issue with your PHP installation. It is able to interpret your project just fine.

The issue is with the project, where the file `header.php` is unable to include `head.php`. I suggest copying your project "phpJoaozinhoEGay" again. Maybe try copying the complete project directory from your other system, where it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the include head to include header...unless your file is actually called head.php

Either way it looks like a spelling mistake on the file or the include